# Disabling the button after once click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to disable a button once it's clicked so the user can't click it more than once. (My application is written in MVC ASP.NET, I've done this in a normal ASP.NET application.)

I tried using JavaScript and jQuery and it's not working. The button is getting disabled but the form is not being submitted.

jQuery:

```
$("#ClickMe").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

JavaScript:

```
function DisableNextButton(btnId) {
    document.getElementById(btnId).disabled = 'true';
}
```

Both methods work great, but now the form won't submit.

Comment: better to use boolean types, not string, because string for: 'false' is notNull, well is notFalse => true.

Comment: Check multiple examples here:
http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Disable-the-Button-After-One-Click-in-NET-MVC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable submit button once it has been clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366828/how-to-disable-submit-button-once-it-has-been-clicked)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

jQuery now has the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function that limits any given event (such as "submit") to one occurrence.

Example:

```
$('#myForm').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

This code will let you submit the form once, then disable the button. Change the selector in the find() function to whatever button you'd like to disable.

**Note:** Per Francisco Goldenstein, I've changed the selector to the form and the event type to submit. This allows you to submit the form from anywhere (places other than the button) while still disabling the button on submit.

**Note 2:** Per gorelog, using `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` will prevent your form from sending the value of the submit button. If you want to pass the button value, use `attr('onclick', 'this.style.opacity = "0.6"; return false;')` instead.

Comment: what happen if i use get(), $('#error').hide(); post error back?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, the above code is a lot less work than manually hiding the entire button and then un-hiding an error message.

Comment: Just a note concerning this method. It will prevent the value of the button from being submitted to POST. So something like `<input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Delete"/>` will not send the value of "cmd" to POST.

Comment: @gorelog I've added a note on how to avoid the problem you've brought up, thanks!

Comment: `button[type="submit"]` should be added to the selector. (for generic code of course).

Comment: @coil I'd recommend changing `input` to `button` in my code above rather than try to blanket all of them. Just my opinion. :)

Answer (score 17):

If when you set disabled="disabled" immediately after the user clicks the button, and the form doesn't submit because of that, you could try two things:

```
//First choice [given myForm = your form]:
myInputButton.disabled = "disabled";
myForm.submit()

//Second choice:
setTimeout(disableFunction, 1);  
//so the form will submit and then almost instantly, the button will be disabled
```

Although I honestly bet there will be a better way to do this, than that.

Comment: Itz thanks for help simple sloution thanks a lot .. 
it works great !!! 
Any way i am open for better solution as well

Comment: don't you need to do this? setTimeout(function () { disableFunction }, 1);

Answer (score 16):

To submit form in MVC NET Core you can submit using **INPUT**:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add This Form">
```

To make it a button I am using Bootstrap for example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add This Form" class="btn btn-primary">
```

To prevent sending duplicate forms in MVC NET Core, you can add **onclick** event, and use **this.disabled = true;** to disable the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add This Form" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.disabled = true;">
```

If you want check first if form is valid and then disable the button, add **this.form.submit();** first, so if form is valid, then this button will be disabled, otherwise button will still be enabled to allow you to correct your form when validated.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add This Form" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true;">
```

You can add text to the disabled button saying you are now in the process of sending form, when all validation is correct using **this.value='text';**:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add This Form" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submitting the form';">
```

Comment: This answer is by far the best of them all - works brilliantly;)

Answer (score 12):

jQuery `.one()` should not be used with the click event but with the `submit` event as described below.

```
 $('input[type=submit]').one('submit', function() {
     $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$("selectorbyclassorbyIDorbyName").click(function () {
  $("selectorbyclassorbyIDorbyName").attr("disabled", true).delay(2000).attr("disabled", false);
});
```

select the button and by its id or text or class ... it just disables after 1st click and enables after 20 Milli sec

Works very well for post backs n place it in Master page, applies to all buttons without calling implicitly like `onclientClick`

Answer (score 3):

### Use modern Js events, with "once"!

```
const button = document.getElementById(btnId);
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Submit form
}, {once : true});

// Disabling works too, but this is a more standard approach for general one-time events
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Comment: Check the CanIUse link. 92% of browsers are currently supported

Answer (score 3):

You could just add the following to your *HTML*:
`<input type="submit" onClick="this.disabled = true;" />`

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

To disable a submit button, you just need to add a disabled attribute to the submit button.

```
$("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
```

To enable a disabled button, set the disabled attribute to false, or remove the disabled attribute.

```
$('#btnSubmit').attr("disabled", false);
```

or

```
$('#btnSubmit').removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent user from making operation twice
        btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
                               "this.disabled=true;" + GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave).ToString() + ";");

        // ... etc. 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

think simple

```
<button id="button1" onclick="Click();">ok</button>
<script>
    var buttonClick = false;
    function Click() {
        if (buttonClick) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            buttonClick = true;
            //todo
            alert("ok");
            //buttonClick = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

if you want run once :)

Answer (score 0):

Set disabled = true inside the function that handles a click.

> document.getElementById(btn.id).disabled = true;