# how to prevent multiple clicks on form button

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the code below to submit values to my db.

```
<input id="btn_'.$temp['id'].'" value="Confirm" style="background: #409940; border-radius: 10px; color: white;" type="button" onclick="validaLink(\''.$temp['id'].'\');">
```

Problem:

with in 2 secs , multiple clicks are submitted with the same value, till the div fads out.

What I have done:
I tried to disabled the form button after submit. but i guess 2 onclick events does not work.

suggestions / code corrections  please

Comment: Consider looking into using sessions and tokens http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html as a server-side method, in conjunction with the other comments below.

Comment: onclick="javascript:window.open(\''.$temp['shorten'].'\'); this.disabled = true;"

Comment: Maybe add this.disabled=true; after your window.open(\''.$temp['shorten'].'\');

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click) answers your question :)

Comment: The comment and link from Nischaal does not answer this question. Joao Paulo's answer is most appropriate for this question.

Comment: i will check all the scanarios ,  and will post here again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will disable the onclick event handler for the button after the first click, and also disable the button itself.

```
onclick="this.onclick=null;this.disabled = true;validaLink(\''.$temp['id'].'\');"
```

Comment: the problem that i am facing .. is  ,, if i  make 20 clicks , before the button disappears. 20 records will be added to the db

Comment: please check the new code .. earlier i copied the wrong line here –

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
onclick="javascript:validaLink(\''.$temp['id'].'\'); this.disabled = true;"
```

Comment: please check the new code .. earlier i copied the wrong line here