# Disabling the button after once click - Part2

Tags: javascript

I'm just a beginner in Java scripting. I am creating a quiz page where all topics are listed in Alphabetical order (e.g. A, B, C...Z).

I would like to have the button disabled after the participant clicks-on one alphabet, but don't know where to insert the script for disabling the button.

This is the simple script:

```
<h1>What Can JavaScript Do?</h1>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello JavaScript!'">
Click Me!</button> 

I have referred this link, but as mentioned above don't know where to insert the disabling script. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click)
```

I will really appreciate if someone can help me out of this problem.

Regards,
Nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h1>What Can JavaScript Do?</h1>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function btnDisable(id){
document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
}
</script>
<button id="btn1" type="button"
onclick="btnDisable('btn1')">
Click Me!</button>
```

Similar to what Reena posted, except the use of the parameter can make the function usable for other questions, too.

Comment: Hi Holden, thank you very much for help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>What Can JavaScript Do?</h1>

<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>

<button type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="disableButton()">Click Me!</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function disableButton() {
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Hello JavaScript!';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Reena for all your help.