# Only Once click Button Disabling using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable a button once it's clicked so the user can't click it more than once. (My application is written in MVC ASP.NET, I've done this in a normal ASP.NET application.)

I tried using JavaScript and jQuery and it's not working. The button is getting disabled but the form is not being submitted.

jQuery:

```
$("#ClickMe").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

JavaScript:

```
function DisableNextButton(btnId) {
    document.getElementById(btnId).disabled = 'true';
}
```

Both methods work great, but now the form won't submit.

Comment: where did you place this code

Comment: disabled  button has nothing to do with form submit. but if disabled button is for submit form . definitely submitting is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery now has the `.one()` function that limits any given event (such as "submit") to one occurrence

Example:

```
$('#myForm').one('submit', function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

This code will let you submit the form once, then disable the button. Change the selector in the find() function to whatever button you'd like to disable.

**Note:** Per Francisco Goldenstein, I've changed the selector to the form and the event type to submit. This allows you to submit the form from anywhere (places other than the button) while still disabling the button on submit.

**Note 2:** Per gorelog, using `attr('disabled','disabled')` will prevent your form from sending the value of the submit button. If you want to pass the button value, use `attr('onclick','this.style.opacity = "0.6"; return false;')` instead.

[DEMO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = $('<button>Click Me</button>');

button.clicked = false;

$('body').append(button);

button.click(function(){
  
  if(button.clicked) return;
  button.clicked = true;
  button.prop('disabled', true);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```