# How can I enable an HTML button based on a PHP Boolean?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to have a button enabled\disabled based on the value of a Boolean the button disabling works however when I try enabling when I require the button to be enabled(after being disabled) it does not work

```
<?php
if($init==0){
    echo "init";
    $booleanSubmitDataButtonDisabled= 1;
    $booleanGetDataButtonDisabled =0;
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['getData'])&&!($booleanOwnerId)) {
    $actionIsdone =1;
    if($actionIsdone){
        disableGetDataEnableSubmit();
    }
}
function disableGetDataEnableSubmit(){
    $init++;
    $booleanGetDataButtonDisabled = 1;
    $booleanSubmitDataButtonDisabled = 0;
    $booleanSelectorDisabled =1;
}
?>
```

and in my form:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="getData" value="Get Data For Selected Action"/></td>
<?php if($booleanSubmitDataButtonDisabled){
                echo "<td><input type='submit'  name='submit' value='Submit' disabled /></td>";
                }else{echo "<td><input type='submit'  name='submit' value='Submit'  /></td>";}  ?>
            <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" <?php if($booleanGetDataButtonDisabled) echo 'disabled="disabled"' ?> /></td>
```

Am I required to somehow make the html in the page refresh? 
I cannot use JavaScript unless this problem absolutely cannot be overcome by using PHP.
Please help with this as I am at my wits end with this problem. 
Thanks in advance
Edit: It seems that what I'm trying to achieve cannot be accomplished with PHP, I'll welcome any answer that shows me how to do this simply 
Thanks

Comment: PHP runs on the server, not the client, it will not run interactively based on browser interactions, for that you'd need to use AJAX, or deal with page refreshes.

Comment: I would use Javascript for this. If you don't want to do that you have to refresh, and rebuild, the page with the enabled or disabled button. Javascipt would be a lot quicker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click holds the answer