# Buttons - How to stop working after clicking on one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code, I have `two` `buttons`, and I want to confirm If the user clicks on any of them, it will execute the `function` (and it already works), but if it clicks again, **it will not do anything**.

My HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Demo</title>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="JS.js"></script>
<!--script src="JS2.js"></script-->
</head>

<body>
  <p><input type="button" name="click" value="Button I" id="1" onclick="myFunction();"/></p>
<p><input type="button" name="click" value="Button II" id="2" onclick="myFunction2();"/></p>

</body>
</html>
```

My functions code (.js):

```
function myFunction(xx, xx, numberOrigin){
    numberOrigin +=1;

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    data: JSON.stringify({
            "xxxxxxxxxxx":xxxxxxx,
            "xxxxxxxxxxxx":xxxxxxxxx,
            "xxxxxxxxxxxx":"xxxxxxx"
    }),
        success:function(output) {
            console.log(output);

            otherFunction(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, numberOrigin);
       },
        error:function(output) {

       }
    });
}
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: Why don't you disable them after clicking?

Comment: What variable do you use to store the nb of clicks on buttons ? where do you test that this is the first time there is a click on one of the buttons ?

Comment: `disable` it at the end of function

Comment: In the case, it's only to disable after clicking. I will create a table in a database to do this check @Cubi, but i'll try it just after. It's just a test

Comment: in the `success function` add `$(".urbtnclass").prop('disabled',true)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling the button after once click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jquery 1.6 and above use:

```
$("input[type='button']").prop("disable", true)
```

For versions less than 1.6 use

```
$("input[type='button']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

I, personally, would put this at the top of your function, before your ajax call.

That way, if there is an error, you can reverse the attributes in your error handler.

> EDIT

after some testing, I saw what you meant by it not working. so here are some alternatives, including the original:

```
$("input")[0].disabled = true;
$("input")[1].disabled = true;
```

Assuming you only have two input buttons and no text boxes.

Another way:

```
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
```

again assuming you have no other inputs on your doc.

Finally, the original answer, with a minor change:

```
$("input[type='button']").prop("disabled", true);
```

Noticed "disable" has been changed to "disabled".

I have tried all of these using Microsoft Edge and each one works. I suggest you start with the first and work your way down until you find a solution that works for you.

Your code would then look like

```
function myFunction(xx, xx, numberOrigin){
    numberOrigin +=1;

    $("input[type='button']").prop("disabled", true); <-- or one of the other choices here

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    data: JSON.stringify({
            "xxxxxxxxxxx":xxxxxxx,
            "xxxxxxxxxxxx":xxxxxxxxx,
            "xxxxxxxxxxxx":"xxxxxxx"
    }),
        success:function(output) {
            console.log(output);

            otherFunction(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, numberOrigin);
       },
        error:function(output) {

       }
    });
}
```

Cheers and good luck

Comment: If you add it on the success function it only disable the button on success ;-).

Comment: putting it in success function doesn't stop it from firing again if the user clicks the button before the ajax returns

Comment: @Alexis Agreed. However, in some cases the user may be able to click twice before the ajax returns. Disabling them at the top should eliminate that possibility. Otherwise I certainly agree with you

Comment: You're right. So disabled at the call and enabled on error.

Comment: I try it but if I click again, the function active again, I dont want this, If user click in the button, the function execute, if user click again, the button will not work again, you can put this with my code pls? Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi Let me work up an example and I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using JQuery, consider using the .one() function. http://api.jquery.com/one/

You'd use it like this. Remove the onclick="myFunction()" from each input element. Then with JQuery in your .js file:

```
/**** add this here ****/
$(function(){
    /* EDIT: I noticed you're wanting to call a different fcn
       depending on which button is clicked. With my solution you 
       could handle this like so: */
    $('input').one('click', function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') !== '2') myFunction();
        else myFunction2();
    });
});

function myFunction(xx, xx, numberOrigin){
    numberOrigin +=1;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "xxxxxxxxxxx":xxxxxxx,
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx":xxxxxxxxx,
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx":"xxxxxxx"
    }),
    success:function(output) {
        console.log(output);
        otherFunction(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, numberOrigin);
    },
    error:function(output) {
       /**** also add here NOTE: in myFunction2() 
             you'll want to call myFunction2 here ****/
      $('input').one('click', myFunction);
    }
    });
}
```

The one() function will unbind after it fires once on each element that matches the selector.

EDIT: if your AJAX request happens to return an error you might want to reattach the click handler to the button. In that case, add the code above into your error callback so the user can click again, if that's the behavior you want.

Comment: Not a good solution. if the result of the ajax is an error btn is locked...

Comment: not sure ajax error handling should be the role of the button. the OP just wants myfunction to fire once, this does that.

Comment: OP want when button make his action he's disabled. We haven't the context. 
If the button does not perform its function it will still be blocked with your solution.

Comment: it will be blocked with every solution. if there's an error, he'll need to reverse whatever course he takes to disable the button

Comment: Thanks for the help @Cruiser. +1