# Django: Several clicks on submit button = several entries in database

Tags: django

I just realised when clicking very fast on the form submit button several times, while it is loading. My POST request is sent several times, meaning I am able to create up to 10 database entries where it's supposed to be only one.

I wasn't aware of this until now and wonder if that is normal behaviour or if there is some issue with my view?

```
def event_detail_view(request, event, organizer):

    queryset = Event.objects.filter(organizer__slug=organizer)
    event = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=event)
    tickets = collect_all_tickets(event, organizer)
    ReserveFormSet = formset_factory(ReserveForm, formset=BaseReserveFormSet, extra=0)
    formset = ReserveFormSet(
        initial=tickets,
        form_kwargs={'organizer_slug': organizer}
        # Example [{'ticket': "Early Bird"}, {'ticket': "Regular Ticket"},]
    )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ReserveFormSet(
            request.POST,
            initial=tickets,
            form_kwargs={'organizer_slug': organizer}
        )
        if formset.is_valid():
            order_reference = unique_order_reference_generator()
            #  TODO Marc: Move into function
            for form in formset:
                ticket_name = form.cleaned_data['ticket'].name
                int_or_empty = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
                qty = is_int_or_zero(int_or_empty)
                if qty > 0:
                    obj = form.save(commit=False)
                    obj.ticket_name = ticket_name
                    obj.order_reference = order_reference
                    obj.save()
            return redirect('organizers:index', organizer=organizer)

    return render(request, 'events/event_detail.html', {'event': event, 'formset': formset})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior, and a common issue with forms online. There are solutions for resolving this, but it's typically done on the front-end, not in your view.

You probably just want to disable the submit button once it's clicked. You can use various ways of doing this. Here are several Javascript options:

https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/doublesubmit/

There's a nice jQuery version in this answer as well:

[Disabling the button after once click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click)