# How can I prevent users from spamming a button?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project and I need to somehow hide or disable a button. The button serves to submit a row on a database.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Efetuar Picagem" class="btn-danger" 
                style="width:300%" onclick="javascript: return ShowMessage();" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using this script to validate the submission. After that I would like to disable or hide this button after clicking it.

```
<script>
    function ShowMessage() {
        ShowMessage.preventDefault();
        var result = confirm("Deseja efetuar picagem?");
        if (result) {



            return true;




        }

        else {
            return false;

        }


    }

</script>
```

Comment: `javascript:` is useless

Comment: `ShowMessage.preventDefault();` makes no sense, the function is not an event object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling the button after once click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use inline events or styles, since that is not in accord to MVC principles and will make it hard to scale your code (add more buttons and functions to your project). I separeted the styles in the CSS (you will need a [link tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)) and the event handling  (with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) in the JS (you will need a [script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)).

Instead of hiding, I'm adding some transparency to communicate that the button was disabled.

You need the event argument in order to call [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
/* yourScript.js */

var btn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');

function showMessage(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents the form submission
  var result = confirm("Deseja efetuar picagem?");
  btn.disabled = result;
}

btn.addEventListener('click', showMessage);
```

```css
/* yourStyle.css */

.btn-danger {
  padding: 1em 4em;
}
.btn-danger[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<!-- css should be added first to prevent frames with no style 
<link href="/path/yourStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Efetuar Picagem" class="btn-danger"/>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- js should be added after your DOM elements
<script src="/path/yourScript.js">
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

In the past (and there could be a more appropriate approach now), I have set the onClick of the button to `$(#btn).prop('disabled', true); setTimeout(ShowMessage, 100);`, not forgetting to enable the button when your finished.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Efetuar Picagem" class="btn-danger" 
                style="width:300%" onclick="submit(this);" />

<script>
    var wasSubmited = false;

    function submit(button) {
        if(!wasSubmited){
            //Submit

            //disable button
            button.setAttribute("disabled", "");
            wasSubmited = true;

            //stop function
            return;
        }

        //Show message that it was already submited

    }
</script>
```