# How to disable button in after click in mithril.js to prevent multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, html, mithril.js

I was able to disable the button after click but the page is not getting submitted, it just got disabled.
How can I submit the page and prevent it from multiple clicks in mithril.js?

```
m(".submit", m("input", {
    type: "submit",
    value: "Send email",
    id: "emailbtn",
    onclick: function () {
       var butn = document.getElementById("emailbtn");
       butn.disabled = true;
    }
}))
```

Comment: Create a snippet of your problem

Comment: I made an answer assuming you were using `m.request` or something to submit the form with JavaScript but are you doing a regular non-JS form submit ?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, 
How can I disable a submit button after a click, to prevent multiple submission in mithril.js?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually set a locking var in the component's closure.  Then use that to control if the submit event is propagated not.  I'm assuming you are not submitting the form with JS.

```
function MyForm() {
    var locked = false;
    function onSubmit(e) {
        console.log('onSubmit');
        if (!locked) {
            // Lock our submit function so it does nothing if triggered again
            locked = true;
            console.log("Send email.");
        } else {
          e.preventDefault();
        }       
    }
    return {
        view: function (vnode) {
            return m('form', {
                method: "post",
                action: "",
                onsubmit: onSubmit
            }, m(".submit", m("input", {
                type: "submit",
                value: "Send email",
                id: "emailbtn",
                disabled: locked,
            })));
        }
    };
}
```

Usually you want to avoid using ids to manipulate the dom like you would in jQuery unless you are using a 3rd party library with actual jQuery.  So in my answer I use the `locked` variable to set the `disabled` property of the input every time it is drawn instead of doing a look up and manipulating the DOM directly.

Mithril documentation on using closure components: https://mithril.js.org/components.html#closure-component-state

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't seem to work as expected. 

I am facing the same issue, after clicking the submit button is getting disabled but the page is not submitted.

Comment: I will change answer to assume you are not using a JavaScript request to submit the form values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the changes @Ian Wilson, it is working now.