# How Do I Stop Customers Clicking Ajax Form Button Twice?

Tags: javascript, opencart, opencart2.x

We have an opencart site (v 2.0.3.1) and are using the worldpay payment module.

Customers are clicking the checkout button at the end of the process more than once before the page can redirect them to our success page. This creates multiple orders for the same cart and charges them each time.

How can I stop the button from submitting the form more than once before it's redirected?

Here is the code for that page:

```
<?php if (!empty($existing_cards)) { ?>
    <legend><?php echo $text_credit_card; ?></legend>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div id="choose-card" class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_card; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="existing-card" value="1" checked="checked"/>
            <?php echo $entry_card_existing; ?>
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="existing-card" value="0"/>
            <?php echo $entry_card_new; ?>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form id="payment-existing-form" action="<?php echo $form_submit; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
        <div id="card-existing">
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="token"><?php echo $entry_cc_choice; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="token" data-worldpay="token" class="form-control">
                <?php foreach ($existing_cards as $existing_card) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $existing_card['token']; ?>"><?php echo $text_card_type . ' ' . $existing_card['type']; ?>, <?php echo $text_card_digits . ' ' . $existing_card['digits']; ?>, <?php echo $text_card_expiry . ' ' . $existing_card['expiry']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="buttons clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right">
              <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_delete_card; ?>" id="button-delete" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-cc-cvc"><?php echo $entry_cc_cvc; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" data-worldpay="cvc" value="" size="4" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_cc_cvc; ?>" id="input-cc-cvc" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="pull-right">
          <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <form style="display: none" id="payment-new-form" action="<?php echo $form_submit; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  <?php } else { ?>
      <form id="payment-new-form" action="<?php echo $form_submit; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <?php } ?>
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-11" id='paymentDetailsHere' style="margin-left: 3%"></div>
      </div>
      <?php if ($worldpay_card) { ?>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-cc-save"><?php echo $entry_card_save; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="checkbox" name="save-card" value=true id="input-cc-save"/>
            </div>
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="payment-errors">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--

      //Load Worldpay.js and run script functions
      $.getScript("<?php echo $worldpay_script; ?>", function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        Worldpay.setClientKey("<?php echo $worldpay_client_key; ?>");

        // disable new card form if existing cards
<?php if (!empty($existing_cards)) { ?>
            $('#payment-new-form :input').prop('disabled', true);
<?php } ?>

        // Set if token is reusable, remove first value when Worldpay update
        Worldpay.reusable = true;
<?php if (isset($recurring_products)) { ?>
            Worldpay.reusable = true;
<?php } else { ?>
            $('input[name=\'save-card\']').on('change', function () {
              if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                Worldpay.reusable = true;
              } else {
                Worldpay.reusable = false;
              }
            });
<?php } ?>

        Worldpay.templateSaveButton = false;
        Worldpay.useTemplate('payment-new-form', 'paymentDetailsHere', 'inline', function (obj) {
          var _el = document.createElement('input');
          _el.value = obj.token;
          _el.type = 'hidden';
          _el.name = 'token';
          document.getElementById('payment-new-form').appendChild(_el);
        });

        //Submit form
        $('input[type=\'submit\']').on('click', function () {
          var existing = $('input[name=\'existing-card\']:checked').val();
          if (existing === '1') {
            var form = document.getElementById('payment-existing-form');
            Worldpay.useForm(form, function (status, response) {
              if (response.error || status != 200) {
                Worldpay.handleError(form, document.getElementById('payment-errors'), response.error);
              } else {
                form.submit();
              }
            }, true);
          } else {
            Worldpay.submitTemplateForm();
          }
        });
      });

      //Delete a card
      $('#button-delete').on('click', function () {
        var token = $('select[name=\'token\'] option:selected');

        if (confirm('<?php echo $text_confirm_delete ?>\n' + token.text())) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=payment/worldpay/deleteCard',
            type: 'post',
            data: {token: token.val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
              $('#button-delete').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function () {
              $('#button-delete').button('reset');
            },
            success: function (json) {
              if (json['error']) {
                alert(json['error']);
              }

              if (json['success']) {
                alert(json['success']);
                if (json['existing_cards']) {
                  token.remove();
                } else {
                  $('input[name=\'existing-card\'][value=0]').click();
                  $('#choose-card').remove();
                  $('#payment-existing-form').remove();
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });

      // enable or disable forms based on exiting or new card option
      $('input[name=\'existing-card\']').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value === '1') {
          $('#payment-existing-form').show();
          $('#payment-new-form').hide();
          $('#payment-new-form :input').prop('disabled', true);
          $('#payment-existing-form :input').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $('#payment-existing-form').hide();
          $('#payment-new-form').show();
          $('#payment-new-form :input').prop('disabled', false);
          $('#payment-existing-form :input').prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });

      });
      //--></script>
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323948/disabling-the-button-after-once-click, some of the answers are javascript/jquery based

Comment: it is the kinematics of your interface which is bad. Any action on an interface must send a signal back to the user that its action had an effect. Leaving the input interface unchanged can only indicate that the action he requests had no effect, so it is normal that he tries to return the same form a second time, or even more. .

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your submit button on click.

```
$('#button-confirm').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled');
});
```